# BizTalk 2013 Schemas in same assembly

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I've just converted an interface from BizTalk 2010 to 2013. After conversion the schemas were not visible to the orchestration.

- I turned off the compile option for the orchestration and it compiles perfectly.
- I found the message(s) that were causing errors and tried to select the type but the schema types were not visible. Types in different assemblies were visible.

As a work around I created a separate project just for the schemas and moved them. I fixed the references to them in the original project and it works fine.

Did the ability to embed schemas in the same assembly as the orchestration change with BizTalk 2013?

Any suggestions how to fix this? I prefer having all the dependencies for an interface in one assembly.

Comment: You can still have the schemas in the same assembly as your Orchestration in BizTalk 2013 & also 2013 R2 so that is not the issue. Without further details or unless someone else has had the same issue and resolved it, it is unlikely that anyone can answer this question.

Comment: Perhaps check the build option on the schemas. Are they set to "BtsCompile" instead of "None"?

Comment: Can you find this schema in the dll using some decompile tool such as dot peek

Comment: I've seen things like this happen...  References likely got messed up during conversion, adding them back to the project manually fixed them.  Make sure files are in the correct namespaces, may have to manually edi the .xsd.cs or .odx files...

Comment: @PieterVandenheede They are set to compile. Good thought

Comment: @Zee Never used that tool. I'll look for it.

Comment: @DanField I'll try that. The namespace is correct. It's wasn't changed during conversion. That has me wondering if a variable in the orchestration has the same type name as a schema and it's making it impossible to find it due to the collision